# What if CRC bits have error in Ethernet Frame?

Tags: networking, ethernet, crc

The Ethernet Frame consists of 32 CRC (Cyclic Redunancy Check) bits for checking errors. Won't  there be a huge problem if the CRC bits themselves are changed but the message/payload is correct?
Is there a way to detect, avoid and correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter crc itself is good or bad, as long as it doesn't match/verify payload (even the payload is still good), this ethernet frame is considered as having a crc error and should be dropped at layer2.

From what I know, in general we don't do any error "correction" with ethernet.  Besides, crc is for error detection, not correction.

However, mainly upper layer protocol (say TCP) is responsible for reliable delivery and does what it should do to retransmit.

Comment: 'Even if the payload is still good' is meaningless. Wrong CRC means something is wrong in the packet. You can't know what it is.

Comment: @EJP "Even if the payload is still good" was referring to OP's question at the end saying "...but the message/payload is correct?"  Not a statement I made.  I know it's meaningless cuz we can't tell it's good.

Answer (score 2):

If the crc of the message does not match the crc after the message, then you only know that there are errors somewhere in the combination of the message and the crc.  You don't know which or where or how many.  If there is a mismatch, you have a transmission error and you need to toss the whole thing.  It will be retransmitted.